# asp.net Bad Request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, devexpress

Im using a lot od devexpress controls. I have noticed that sometimes i think mainly while making callbacks on devexpress controlls there is a timeout and nothing happens. Then when I try to klick on another link or something (for example refresh page) there is http 400: Bad Request.

I cant do anything till I delete cookies, then everything works ok.

Where can be the problem ?

When I use visual studio development server sometimes even process of that server is getting down and I have to restart it

Comment: you can simply contact the specific third party control vendor to get best results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't heard of this problem before and I do not remember that our customers reported such problems to us.  It would be better if you create a ticket in the [support center](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/) and post your code there.  BTW, does this problem appears only on a certain page or you see it everywhere on your site?  Which version of our controls are you using?  I suggest that you try the latest one (10.1.6).